# Java 8 : groupby with Comparator

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of int for example (1,2,4,6,7,8).
I want to know if there is away in Java 8 to create a list of lists.

If

```
(x,y)->x+1=y
```

it should be in the same list.

In this example the output should be:

```
(1,2), (4), (6,7,8)
```

I can write in this way :

```
public static List<List<int>> group(List<int> list, GroupFunctionByOrder groupFunction) {

    List<List<int>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int l : list) {

        boolean groupFound = false;
        for (List<int> group : result) {
            if (groupFunction.sameGroup(l, group.get(group.size()-1))) {
                group.add(l);
                groupFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (! groupFound) {
            List<int> newGroup =  new ArrayList<>();
            newGroup.add(l);
            result.add(newGroup);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public class GroupFunctionByOrder {
    public boolean sameGroup(int l1, int  l2){
        return l1+1 == l2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried anything if yes , then add else people will start downvoting the question

Comment: There is no `List<List<int>>` in Java. Besides that, you sure mean `sameGroup(group.get(group.size()-1), l)` instead of `sameGroup(l, group.get(group.size()-1))`…

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
List<List<Integer>> grouped = StreamEx.of(1,2,4,6,7,8)
        .groupRuns((x, y) -> x + 1 == y)
        .toList();
```

Comment: Should be mentioned that this requires the stream to be sorted. The question doesn’t indicate whether this is given or just coincidence in the sample data…

Comment: I feel this answer should come with the giant caveat that this is using an extension library, and is not native Java 8 streams.  Additionally this answer goes to reinforce my point in my own answer:  without the ability to access `BiFunction` or `BiPredicate`, something like this isn't possible.  StreamEx gives one access to that, so logically this makes sense.

Comment: @Holger I suspect it's not a coincidence, judging from the identical lambda. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Makoto well, StreamEx is built atop the original stream API, so you could do the same without the extension library, calling it a genuine Stream solution, though it would require quiet some code…

Answer (score 1):

No, this likely isn't possible.

Because of the *very nature* of streams - you do not have any insight into what value is next processed, nor can you pull values in from an arbitrary point in the stream - doing something like this is not feasible from a Java streams standpoint.

Chiefly, you cannot gain access to `BiFunction` or `BiPredicate` in a stream context.  If you could, then you'd stand a chance at splitting the values up based on the sequence of what came prior.

Comment: I don't see why it's against the very nature of streams, considering they already support ordering, reduction, and stateful operations. Seems more of a pragmatic limitation to me.

Comment: It is obviously possible with a stateful intermediate operation.

Comment: @shmosel:  Streams aren't limited to finite sets.  They can be infinite, too.  They were likely designed with that in mind.

Comment: @Makoto I don't see your point. Many operations will hang on infinite streams, but that doesn't mean they're against the very nature of streams.

Comment: @shmosel: The point is, the operation the OP wants to do really doesn't work given the way that streams were implemented to begin with. You can't look forwards or backwards in a stream.  You also can't store state in the middle of a stream.  If you wanted to process elements like this, you'd have to store information temporarily (something not supported natively), or replay the stream (somewhat inefficient).  As a refresher I'd encourage you to look at [the package description for `Stream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Comment: But you *can* look forwards, and you *can* store state. Again, consider reduction and stateful operations.

Answer (score 1):

What works in java7 works in java8 as well :)

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,6,7,8);
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Integer> prev = new ArrayList<>();
        prev.add(list.get(0));

        //iterate over the list
        for (int i = 1 ; i < list.size(); i++){
            // Add to list if does not satisfy condition
            if (list.get(i) != list.get(i-1) +1){
                result.add(prev);
                prev = new ArrayList();
            }
            prev.add(list.get(i));
        }

        result.add(prev);

        // print result
        for(List<Integer> p : result) {
            Object[] arr = p.toArray();
            System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a straightforward way in Java 8, but here's an alternative solution:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8);

List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
int start = 0, i = 1, size = list.size();
while (i < size) {
    while (i < size && list.get(i - 1) + 1 == list.get(i)) i++;
    result.add(list.subList(start, i));
    start = i++;
}

System.out.println(result); // [[1, 2], [4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

This uses [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-), which returns a sublist view backed by the original list. The idea of this code is to shift the index until the condition is broken, add the sublist to the result and then start again from that point.